# Habilitar CORS en odoo 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, backend, odoo

Intento habilitar en odoo 11 el Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado, **CORS** por sus siglas en ingles ( **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**). He visto algunos articulos referente al tema pero no he logrado dar con la respuesta correcta.

Se envia una solicitud hacia el api de odoo desde una aplicacion desarrollada con Angular 7.

Segun la explicacion dada en el articulo

https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/avoid-cors-error-webapp-cordova-99048

para habilitar el CORS en Odoo se debe editar la funcion wsgi_xmlrpc() que se encuentra en el fichero wsgi_server.py

```
def wsgi_xmlrpc(environ, start_response):

    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "OPTIONS":

        response = werkzeug.wrappers.Response('OPTIONS METHOD DETECTED') 

        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'

        response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 1000

        # note that '*' is not valid for Access-Control-Allow-Headers

        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept'


        return response(environ, start_response)



    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith('/xmlrpc/'):

        length = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])

        data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)

        # Distinguish betweed the 2 faultCode modes

        string_faultcode = True

        if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith('/xmlrpc/2/'):

            service = environ['PATH_INFO'][len('/xmlrpc/2/'):]

            string_faultcode = False

        else:

            service = environ['PATH_INFO'][len('/xmlrpc/'):]

        params, method = xmlrpclib.loads(data)

        return xmlrpc_return(start_response, service, method, params, string_faultcode)
```

En environ['PATH_INFO'] no va a venir la secuencia '/xmlrpc/', por lo que nunca va a entrar al fragmento de codigo encapsulado en => if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith('/xmlrpc/'):

Por lo tanto se ejecuta el fragmento:

```
if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] in ['POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']:

        response = werkzeug.wrappers.Response(str(environ['REQUEST_METHOD'])+' METHOD DETECTED')

        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'

        response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 1000

        # note that '*' is not valid for Access-Control-Allow-Headers

        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept'


        return response(environ, start_response)
```

El Response devuelve codigo 200 y en las cabeceras de dicha respuesta se encuentra las definidas anteriormente. Sin embargo en la consola del navegador en modo desarrollo muestra lo siguiente:

Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v42/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2 (razón: la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no coincide con 'https://angular.io').

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Te marca algún error, y si es así, que te arroja la consola? ¿Que llevas hecho?

Comment: Lo mas cercano que encontre fue esto: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/avoid-cors-error-webapp-cordova-99048 . Pero cuando lo implemento y ejecuto en la consola del navegador menciona que no se tiene permiso pues el en cabezado Access-Control-Allow-Origin no esta habilitado.

Comment: Sería bueno que colocaras código para entender mejor tu problema.

Comment: @FernandoCarraro extendi la explicacion en la pregunta

Comment: Muchas veces el problema es del lado de la aplicación servidor y no permita que te conectes a algún servicio por cuestiones de seguridad.

Según lo que entiendo, tienes una aplicación en Odoo (que usa Python) y quieres acceder a un servicio  de una aplicación Angular 7.